# Return single array from foreach class function

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm working on a PHP class function using foreach on array strings. It's used to query the DB and it should return a new array when called.

The code looks like this:

```
public function myForeach() {

   $arrayOne = $getData;

   foreach($arrayOne as $key=>$value){
      $query = // query the value in the DB;
   }
   return $query;
}else {
   return false;

}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here. What I want the output to be is a new array from the $query.

At the moment, it returns an array like :

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "returnedstring" }
```

A single string array, rather than each value from the foreach.

I want to return this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "returnedstring1" [1]=> string(15) "returnedstring2"}
```

Comment: You're *returning* on the first iteration of your `foreach` loop. Of course it's only going to return a single value

Comment: Your use `return` statement in `foreach` and this code returning from function after first iteration.

You must merge (`array_merge`) result query in `foreach` and next return.

Comment: Edit, I just tried it without that, it still returns a single string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return the `$query` parameter inside the `foreach`, then you have an `else` that dont fit in anywhere (`else` requires an `if` to be an `else` for).  You will also need to `append` the value to the array:

```
public function myForeach() {
  $arrayOne = $getData;
  $query = array(); // Create the $query array.
  foreach($arrayOne as $key=>$value){
    $query[] = // Append the query array with whatever value you have.
  }
  return $query; // Return the array when the for-each loop is done.
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by append. could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Every iteration of the foreach loop, you assign the `$query` parameter with the value you want to add to the array (`$query = /../`), that means that it will replace whatever value you have stored in it with the new value. You will have to add a new object to the array, which you can do by using: `$query[] = /../`.

Comment: Happy to help, feel free to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

change your code,

```
$query = // query the value in the DB;
return $query;
```

To

```
$query[] = // query the value in the DB;
```

Note: no if() is visible for else?